# submit form after validation jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, form-submit

I have following form:

```
<form id="form" action="comments.php" method="post">
  <ul>
    <li><div class="formbox_titles">Name</div><input type="text" name="name" class="required comm_input" /></li>
    <li><div class="formbox_titles">Email</div><input type="text" name="email" class="required comm_input"/></li>
    <li><div class="formbox_titles">Message</div><textarea name="message" class="required comm_text"></textarea></li>
    <li><input type="submit" value="Submit"></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

and following JQuery for form submission:

```
target: '#preview', 
  success: function() { 
  $('#formbox').slideUp('fast'); 
}
```

Now the problem is that I also have form validation JQuery code

```
$().ready(function() {
    // validate comment form
    $("#form").validate({ 
    });
});
```

Both of them work great and form does popup warning that all three fields cant be empty but the date inside form is submitted into database anyway. Im using following code for form validation http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ So the question is how to add first jquery inside second, so first will be executed once the required fields are filled?

Hope someone will help. Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

If you want to submit the form manually, you have to bypass jQuery bound event. You can do it in either of these ways:

```
$('#form_id')[0].submit();
```

or

```
$('#form_id').get(0).submit();
```

**[0] or get(0) gives you the DOM object instead of the jQuery object.**

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out... Was looking for this as I have a event bound to submiting the form but before I actually send the form I have to do an AJAX request and if the condition is true I submit the form and there I needed the bypass. +1

Answer (score 18):

From your example, I am not clear about the control flow of your page, however, I am assuming you are calling the `submit()` method somewhere. After you have validated the form and before you submit it, check it's validation with the `valid()` method. Your code should look something like this:

```
$("#form").validate();
if ($('#form').valid())
    $('#form').submit();
```

Answer (score 4):

I do not know anything about your validation plugin, but normally u could use this peace of code

```
<script>

    $("form").submit(function() {
      if (validationIsTrue()) {
        return true;
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
    });
</script>
```

You have to make your validation and then return true / false to the submit function of the form. If the plugin does return a bool value, you can try something like this:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
   return $(this).validate({ .... });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

When you say that the "date inside form is submitted" that makes no sense to me because in your code snippets I see nothing called "date".

I've used the .validate() plugin extensively...
What I can tell you that may help is that the validate plugin you're using has a submitHandler function that you can use...

```
// validate comment form
$("#form").validate({
submitHandler : function(form) {
    //do something here
    form.submit();
}
});
```

The submitHandler is called only if all the rules for validation are met.  Namely in your case you have three fields with "required" on them which means that this form will NOT be submitted unless all three fields have a value.

With that, I can tell you for sure that with the information provided there is nothing to indicate the problem you're describing.  Providing more and better information will help us figure out what's wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can use submitHandler from JQuery form validate plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/jquery.min.js" ></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".form").validate({
        rules: {
            userName: {
                required: true
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            userName: {
                required: "specify userName"
            },
            password: {
                required: "specify password"
            }
        },
        errorClass: "help-inline text-danger",
        errorElement: "span",
        highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).parents('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            $(element).parents('.form-group').addClass('has-success');
        },
        submitHandler: function(form,e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('Form submitted');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'authenticate.jsp',
                dataType: "html",
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                success: function(result) {
                    window.location.href = "dashboard.jsp";
                },
                error : function(error) {

                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

});  
</script>
```