# How to excute code after form validation within Google Tag Manager constrictions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

I need to call a tracking code when a form is submit and after it is validated using Google Tag Manager. I do not have direct access to the site code. I can only execute script from Google Tag Manager.

I've searched the [web for an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15632607/google-tag-manager-calling-datalayer-push-after-validating-the-form), but I could not find something that worked.

I've tried:

```
jQuery('#formId').on('submit',function(){
    console.log('test');
})
```

But this prints "test" before the form validates the fields, so if I leave a field blank, it still prints "test".

I've tried different approaches that [I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638641/submit-form-after-validation-jquery):

```
jQuery('#formId').on('submit',function(){
    if (jQuery('#formId').valid()){
     console.log('test');
    }
})
```

or

```
jQuery('#formId').on('submit',function(){
    if (jQuery(this).valid()){
     console.log('test');
    }
})
```

or

```
jQuery('#formId').on('submit',function(event){
    if (jQuery(event).valid()){
     console.log('test');
    }
})
```

But they all return `VM914:2 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).valid is not a function`

How can I run a script from Google Tag Manager that runs on formsubmit after the form validation?

Comment: Does $("#formId").valid(); instead of jQuery('#formId').valid() work ?

Comment: jquery doesn't natively have any kind of form validation function. They have plugins for it... are you able to use external libraries or just vanilla jquery? if just jquery, you're gona need to write up your own validation plugin if you want this to be reusable in any sense. If you just want a one off, well then the easiest thing is just to cycle the form values and manually check the validation rules

Comment: you told "it prints "test" before the form validates the fields"..so what kind of validation does exit there already?

Comment: What validation they use on that page?

Comment: Do you have an URL to test?

Comment: https://www.sportlink.com.br/a-melhor-grama-sintetica/

This is the site in question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given site (https://www.sportlink.com.br/a-melhor-grama-sintetica/) uses Wordpress.

The contact form in question has the class `wpcf7`. A web search indicated that the form and its validation logic is implemented by the Wordpress plugin [Contact Form 7](https://contactform7.com/) (its JavaScript logic is [*currently available here*](https://www.sportlink.com.br/wp-content/cache/autoptimize/js/autoptimize_cf5094bbf7172d1cd909142056f53abf.js), compressed by Autoptimize)

Fortunately, Confact Form 7 provides custom events to hook into their validation logic, which are documented here:  https://contactform7.com/dom-events/.

Solution for your question:

```js
jQuery('.wpcf7').on('wpcf7mailsent', function(event) {
    console.log('test');
});
```

Notes:

- `wpcf7submit` was not sufficient in my tests, this fired even for invalid forms
- in case of only one contact form, `jQuery('.wpcf7')` works also (so you don't need to know the `#formid`, if that's a problem)

Comment: In addition to the original answer, form input values are available on the `event.detail.inputs`

Answer (score 4):

you seem to be trying to use the jquery validate plugin, which is not native jquery. you can add it via a script tag:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```

but to use the `valid` function, you actually need to set validation rules ahead of time:

```
var form = jQuery('#formId');


form.validate() 
form.on('submit', function(event) {
  if (form.valid()) {
    consoel.log('good now')
  }
})
```

this will cause validation against any web native validation directives on the inputs in the form, if this is NOT using web native validation directive, (like it's using angular or some external lib), you'll need to manually define validation rules in your `validate` function or do something completely different... here are the docs: https://jqueryvalidation.org/

fair warning, the validate and valid functions actually do DOM manipulation and can override event listeners applied elsewhere, so tread carefully. You're doing this with your hands tied behind your back not just having access to the site code.

here's a stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/jquery-m7qkpy?file=index.html

if you can't add an external plugin, well then that changes a lot.